# Reshape dataframe so that each entry of column in repeated over all other columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, reshape2

I have a data.frame, dat, which looks like this

```r
dat = data.frame(x = c(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3), y = c(2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3), output = c(2, 10, 101, 100))
```

```r
    x   y output
1 1.0 2.0      2
2 1.1 2.1     10
3 1.2 2.2    101
4 1.3 2.3    100
```

I want that each pair of elements of columns "x" and "output" is repeated over column "y".

I have tried using `tidyr::spread`, `tidyr::gather`, and `reshape2::melt` to no avail. This is because I am a beginner in using `tidyr` and `reshape2` and other reshaping packages.

Currently, I have resorted to using a loop to extract each element pair from columns "x" and "output" and creating a new data.frame, `final_df`, that combines the resulting data.frames. I believe this is definitely not the most efficient way to do it and am confident that there is a one-liner function somewhere which can do this magic for me.

In the resulting data.frame, if I subset the data.frame using say,

```
dplyr::filter(final_df, x == 1, output == 2)
```

it should look like so:

```r
data.frame(x = rep(1, dat$x[1], nrow(dat)), y = dat$y, output = rep(dat$output[1], nrow(dat)))
```

```r
  x   y output
1 1 2.0      2
2 1 2.1      2
3 1 2.2      2
4 1 2.3      2
```

I will be happy with an answer using tidyverse. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain on this part: `each pair of elements of columns "x" and "output" is repeated over column "y"`? How many times do you want a pair to repeat?

Comment: I want to keep y fixed and repeat each x and output pair to match with the length of y, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% mutate(y1=paste(y,collapse = ',')) %>% separate_rows(y1)
```

If there is no duplication in *x* and *output*  i.e we can treat them as an *ID* column then we can use `tidyr::complete`

```
dat %>% complete(nesting(x,output),y)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution:

```r
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
 dat %>% select(-y) %>% crossing(dat %>% select(y))
```

```r
     x output   y
1  1.0      2 2.0
2  1.0      2 2.1
3  1.0      2 2.2
4  1.0      2 2.3
5  1.1     10 2.0
6  1.1     10 2.1
7  1.1     10 2.2
8  1.1     10 2.3
9  1.2    101 2.0
10 1.2    101 2.1
11 1.2    101 2.2
12 1.2    101 2.3
13 1.3    100 2.0
14 1.3    100 2.1
15 1.3    100 2.2
16 1.3    100 2.3
```